# Decrypting strings in Python that were encrypted with MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256 in PHP

Tags: php, python, encryption, mcrypt

I have a function in PHP that encrypts text as follows:

```
function encrypt($text)
{
    $Key = "MyKey";

    return trim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $Key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, mcrypt_create_iv(mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB), MCRYPT_RAND))));
}
```

How do I decrypt these values in Python?

Comment: nobody can decrypt this, you throw away the iv.

Comment: @hop - ECB mode can be decrypted without the IV. The IV is not used in ECB mode for encryption or decryption.

Comment: @birryree: right! i only saw that the iv argument was set and assumed… this shows why you don't write your whole programm in one line.

Comment: @dharmesh - I am attempting to solve your problem, but thanks to PHP, the `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` algorithm is not the same as `AES 256` (more rounds are done in Rijndael). I have to find a Python implementation or pure Rijndael 256, which it doesn't seem like PyCrypto nor M2Crypto support.

Comment: @dharmesh: why don't you use something common on the php side in the first place?

Comment: That would be a good option too - Rijndael-256 is not as widely used, and if you want to use AES, you would be using Rijndael-128 (`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`). PHP's versions of Rijndael 192 and 256 are not AES-compatible. dharmesh - the simplest way would be to decrypt and re-encrypt your existing data with `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128`, which would allow you to use popular Python libraries to decrypt your data.

Comment: Are you using Python 2.x or 3.x?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

To decrypt this form of encryption, you will need to get a version of Rijndael.  One can be found [here](http://wiki.birth-online.de/snippets/python/aes-rijndael).  Then you will need to simulate the key and text padding used in the PHP Mcrypt module.  They add `'\0'` to pad out the text and key to the correct size.  They are using a 256 bit block size and the key size used with the key you give is 128 (it may increase if you give it a bigger key).  Unfortunately, the Python implementation I've linked to only encodes a single block at a time.  I've created python functions which simulate the encryption (for testing) and decryption in Python

```
import rijndael
import base64

KEY_SIZE = 16
BLOCK_SIZE = 32

def encrypt(key, plaintext):
    padded_key = key.ljust(KEY_SIZE, '\0')
    padded_text = plaintext + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(plaintext) % BLOCK_SIZE) * '\0'

    # could also be one of
    #if len(plaintext) % BLOCK_SIZE != 0:
    #    padded_text = plaintext.ljust((len(plaintext) / BLOCK_SIZE) + 1 * BLOCKSIZE), '\0')
    # -OR-
    #padded_text = plaintext.ljust((len(plaintext) + (BLOCK_SIZE - len(plaintext) % BLOCK_SIZE)), '\0')

    r = rijndael.rijndael(padded_key, BLOCK_SIZE)

    ciphertext = ''
    for start in range(0, len(padded_text), BLOCK_SIZE):
        ciphertext += r.encrypt(padded_text[start:start+BLOCK_SIZE])

    encoded = base64.b64encode(ciphertext)

    return encoded


def decrypt(key, encoded):
    padded_key = key.ljust(KEY_SIZE, '\0')

    ciphertext = base64.b64decode(encoded)

    r = rijndael.rijndael(padded_key, BLOCK_SIZE)

    padded_text = ''
    for start in range(0, len(ciphertext), BLOCK_SIZE):
        padded_text += r.decrypt(ciphertext[start:start+BLOCK_SIZE])

    plaintext = padded_text.split('\x00', 1)[0]

    return plaintext
```

This can be used as follows:

```
key = 'MyKey'
text = 'test'

encoded = encrypt(key, text)
print repr(encoded)
# prints 'I+KlvwIK2e690lPLDQMMUf5kfZmdZRIexYJp1SLWRJY='

decoded = decrypt(key, encoded)
print repr(decoded)
# prints 'test'
```

For comparison, here is the output from PHP with the same text:

```
$ php -a
Interactive shell

php > $key = 'MyKey';
php > $text = 'test';
php > $output = mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);
php > $encoded = base64_encode($output);
php > echo $encoded;
I+KlvwIK2e690lPLDQMMUf5kfZmdZRIexYJp1SLWRJY=
```

Comment: Absolutely brilliant! I was able to get your test code running. Then, I ran the decrypt function (in Python) against encrypted values from PHP. Works like a charm. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: apart from the key len > block size part you should use string.ljust() to pad the key.

Comment: @hop Thanks for the heads up on string.ljust(). I've updated the key padding to use that.  The text padding still seems better the other way.

Comment: What is required to adapt this script to Python 3?

Comment: @101100 Installed package using "pip install rijndael" but giving error. 
r = rijndael.rijndael(padded_key, BLOCK_SIZE)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'rijndael'

Comment: @101100 I have try this code but its give me attribute error "AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'rijndael'"

Answer (score 4):

If you're willing to use MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128 rather than 256 on the PHP side, this is as simple as:

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64
key="MyKey"

def decrypt(text)
    cipher=AES.new(key)
    return cipher.decrypt(base64.b64decode(text))
```

Comment: Thanks. I think it's worth noting that `Crypto` module can be found in [`pycrypto`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pycrypto).

Answer (score 2):

Although the answer from @101100 was a good one at the time, it's no longer viable. The reference is now a broken link, and the code would only run on older Pythons (<3).

Instead, the [pprp project](https://pypi.org/project/pprp) seems to fill the void nicely. On Python 2 or Python 3, just `pip install pprp`, then:

```
import pprp
import base64

KEY_SIZE = 16
BLOCK_SIZE = 32


def encrypt(key, plaintext):
    key = key.encode('ascii')
    plaintext = plaintext.encode('utf-8')
    padded_key = key.ljust(KEY_SIZE, b'\0')

    sg = pprp.data_source_gen(plaintext, block_size=BLOCK_SIZE)
    eg = pprp.rjindael_encrypt_gen(padded_key, sg, block_size=BLOCK_SIZE)

    ciphertext = pprp.encrypt_sink(eg)

    encoded = base64.b64encode(ciphertext)

    return encoded.decode('ascii')


def decrypt(key, encoded):
    key = key.encode('ascii')
    padded_key = key.ljust(KEY_SIZE, b'\0')

    ciphertext = base64.b64decode(encoded.encode('ascii'))

    sg = pprp.data_source_gen(ciphertext, block_size=BLOCK_SIZE)
    dg = pprp.rjindael_decrypt_gen(padded_key, sg, block_size=BLOCK_SIZE)

    return pprp.decrypt_sink(dg).decode('utf-8')


key = 'MyKey'
text = 'test'

encoded = encrypt(key, text)
print(repr(encoded))
# prints 'ju0pt5Y63Vj4qiViL4VL83Wjgirq4QsGDkj+tDcNcrw='

decoded = decrypt(key, encoded)
print(repr(decoded))
# prints 'test'
```

I'm a little dismayed that the ciphertext comes out different than what you see with 101100's answer. I have, however, used this technique to successfully decrypt data encrypted in PHP as described in the OP.

Comment: getting issue in encrypt_sink
    s.write(block)
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Comment: @PiyushShukla It appears that https://github.com/dsoprea/RijndaelPbkdf/issues/9 is a regression with pprp 0.2.7. You'll need to install `pprp==0.2.6` to work around the issue until it's fixed.