# javascript alternative to mcrypt_encrypt

Tags: php, javascript, encryption

i am trying to find out is there a javascript library out there that gives functionality for mcrypt_encrypt in php.

I am writing a function to access my api using javascript. i always encrypt and encode my parameters. This is the method i would like to have a js version of.

```
public function sendRequest($request_params)
{
    //encrypt the request parameters
    $enc_request = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $this->_app_key, json_encode($request_params), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));

    //create the params array, which will
    //be the POST parameters
    $params = array();
    $params['enc_request'] = $enc_request;
    $params['app_id'] = $this->_app_id;

    //initialize and setup the curl handler
    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $this->_api_url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $params);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);

    //execute the request
    $result = curl_exec($ch);

    //json_decode the result
    $result = @json_decode($result);
    //if everything went great, return the data
    return $result;
}
```

This is the jquery version of the above request ive come up with but it always returns an invalid request. meaning the API fails to decrypt the request

```
        var queryAPI = function (request_object,callback)
        {
            var app_key = 'sdffkjhdsjfhsdjkfhsdkj';
            var app_secret = 'hfszdhfkjzxjkcxzkjb';
            var app_url = 'http://www.veepiz.com/api/jsonp.php';
            var enc_request = $.toJSON(request_object);
            var ciphertext =encode64(Crypto.AES.encrypt(enc_request, app_secret, { mode: new Crypto.mode.ECB }));
            $.post(app_url,{'app_id':app_key,'enc_request':ciphertext},
            function (data)
            {
                console.log(data);
            },'jsonp');

        }
```

here is how i run the above function

```
                        var request={'controller':'user','action':'login','emailaddress':email,'password':pass};
                        queryAPI(request,function (d){console.log(d);});
```

on the server side api, here is how php decrypts the request

```
$params = json_decode(trim(mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $app_secret, base64_decode( urldecode( $enc_request )), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB )));
//check if the request is valid by checking if it's an array and looking for the controller and action
if( $params == false || isset($params->controller) == false || isset($params->action) == false ) {
    $result['success'] = 0;
    $result['errormsg'] = "Request is not valid! ";
    //echo the result of the API call
    header('Cache-Control: no-cache, must-revalidate');
    header('Expires: Mon, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT');
    header('Content-type: application/javascript');        
    $result=json_encode($result);
    # JSON if no callback
    if( ! isset($_GET['callback']))
        exit( $result );

    # JSONP if valid callback
    if(is_valid_callback($_GET['callback']))
        exit( "{$_GET['callback']}($result)" );

    # Otherwise, bad request
    header('Status: 400 Bad Request', true, 400);                     
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try with [crypto-js](http://code.google.com/p/crypto-js/), or one of the descendants [ezcrypto](https://github.com/ElmerZhang/ezcrypto) or [cryptojs](https://github.com/gwjjeff/cryptojs). I think `AES` is the same as Rijndael.

Comment: just tried crpto.js and i think its failing me, ive also done edits to the question, so please advise

Comment: Try logging the output after encrypting and base64-encoding on the client, before and after url decoding, base64-decoding and decryption so we have a chance to see where it goes awry.

Comment: ok on js side...console.log(encode64(Crypto.AES.encrypt("ferguson", "jordah", { mode: new Crypto.mode.ECB }))); returns "RlpVN1lMc3dvbTZKSTIvS2VXekk2dyUzRCUzRA==" without quotes. on php i run mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, "jordah", base64_decode("RlpVN1lMc3dvbTZKSTIvS2VXekk2dyUzRCUzRA=="), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB ); and it returns null

Comment: Add the log output to your question, please. According to [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217269/decrypting-strings-in-python-that-were-encrypted-with-mcrypt-rijndael-256-in-php#comment10106723_8217269) _PHP's versions of Rijndael 192 and 256 are not AES-compatible._

Comment: ok i have tried this javascript side. its better  i give a simple test . console.log(encode64(Crypto.AES.encrypt("ferguson", "jordah", { mode: new Crypto.mode.ECB }))); //output RlpVN1lMc3dvbTZKSTIvS2VXekk2dyUzRCUzRA==. when i try to decrypt it using php mcrypt, $va=mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, "jordah", base64_decode("RlpVN1lMc3dvbTZKSTIvS2VXekk2dyUzRCUzRA=="), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB ); ---> i get null

Answer (score 0):

ok i solved this with AES and i found out to always(serverside) urldecode($enc_request) as base64 '=' would alter when posted to the url. The tutorial i used is here [JavaScript and PHP Encryption – The Secret Handshake](http://www.untwistedvortex.com/javascript-php-encryption-secret-handshake/)

apparently my problem was being brought up by a problematic encode64() javascript function that returned an invalid base64 string