# Encrypt in PHP, Decrypt in Python

Tags: php, python, encryption, cross-language

PHP code:

```
$key = "12345678abcdefgh12345678abcdefgh";
$iv = "12345678abcdefgh";
$plaindata = "This is a test string.";

$enc = base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, $key, $plaindata, MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, $iv));

echo($enc);
```

Result:

```
QBN0Yue3D9hBrBuD01n5KWG+lv2doMf97cKm/AeusAI=
```

How can this be decrypted in Python?

Comment: See this related answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/8232171/623518

Comment: That answer decrypts using ECB mode and does not use an iv. I want to decrypt in CBC mode using an iv.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try something like this (altho i do have PyCrypto installed)

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
import base64

AES.key_size=128
iv="your iv"
key="your key"
crypt_object=AES.new(key=key,mode=AES.MODE_CBC,IV=iv)

decoded=base64.b64decode(plain) # your ecrypted and encoded text goes here
decrypted=crypt_object.decrypt(decoded)
```

This will bring the decoded text but it will be padded with bytes for it to be a size multiple of 16.

You should probably decide on a proper padding scheme and remove it afterwards accordingly

Comment: Thank you very much. Just in case somebody is stuck with installing PyCrypto, follow the instructions here http://apprenticealf.wordpress.com/2011/01/14/windows-python-ebooks-and-drm/

Comment: I got this error `TypeError: argument of type 'int' is not iterable`

Answer (score -9):

Read [the manual](http://docs.python.org/library/base64.html), its pretty well documented.

```
data = base64.b64decode('QBN0Yue3D9hBrBuD01n5KWG+lv2doMf97cKm/AeusAI=')
```

Comment: Your question was to decrypt the base64 result. After encrypting something one way you cant revert it. Thats the point of it.

Comment: `base64.decode` takes two arguments, so your code will raise a `TypeError`. I think you meant to use `base64.b64decode` or `base64.decodestring`. Also, what is with the semi-colon, and your answer does not decrypt the decoded string.

Comment: In PHP, there's a decrypt function for mcrypt. I believe what OP wants is an equivalent to this, in addition to `base64.b64decode` of course. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.mcrypt-decrypt.php

Comment: I can decrypt in PHP, I just need to decrypt the final result in Python to get back the plain data "This is a test string."