# PHP function conversion to Python

Tags: php, python

I am just wondering is it possible to convert `PHP` encryption function to Python? I am using `PHP` function to encrypt `USER ID` and store it in `Database` and now I need to decrypt `USER ID` in `Python`, I using this `PHP` function:

```
function decrypt($id) {
       $cryptKey  = '123';
       $decoded    = rtrim( mcrypt_decrypt( MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, md5( $cryptKey ),         base64_decode( $id ), MCRYPT_MODE_CBC, md5( md5( $cryptKey ) ) ), "\0");
       return( $decoded );
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Decrypting strings in Python that were encrypted with MCRYPT\_RIJNDAEL\_256 in PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8217269/decrypting-strings-in-python-that-were-encrypted-with-mcrypt-rijndael-256-in-php)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is your function 'translated' to python

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from hashlib import md5

def decrypt(id): 
    cryptKey  = '123'
    cipher = AES.new(key=md5(cryptKey).hexdigest(), mode=AES.MODE_CBC, IV=md5(md5(cryptKey).hexdigest()).hexdigest()[:16])
    decoded = cipher.decrypt(id.decode('base64')).rstrip('\0')
    return decoded
```

A fiew suggestions
 1. Use a random iv
 2. Use a more complex key
 3. Don't hardcode the key
 4. Use `openssl_decrypt` , `mcrypt_decrypt` is deprecated

**Note**
This will not work with `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256` because it uses 32 byte blocks .
But you could use `MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128` or `openssl`

Here is an example with openssl AES CBC in PHP :

```
function encrypt($data, $key) {
    $method = "aes-" . strlen($key) * 8 . "-cbc";
    $iv = openssl_random_pseudo_bytes(16);
    $encoded = base64_encode($iv . openssl_encrypt($data, $method, $key, TRUE, $iv));
    return $encoded;
}

function decrypt($data, $key) {
    $method = "aes-" . strlen($key) * 8 . "-cbc";
    $iv = substr(base64_decode($data), 0, 16);
    $decoded = openssl_decrypt(substr(base64_decode($data), 16), $method, $key, TRUE, $iv);
    return $decoded;
}
```

Python code :

```
from Crypto.Cipher import AES
from Crypto import Random
import base64

def encrypt(data, key): 
    pkcs7pad = lambda data: data + chr(16-(len(data)%16)).encode() * (16-(len(data)%16))
    iv = Random.new().read(16)
    cipher = AES.new(key=key, mode=AES.MODE_CBC, IV=iv)
    encoded = base64.b64encode(iv + cipher.encrypt(pkcs7pad(data)))
    return encoded

def decrypt(data, key): 
    pkcs7unpad = lambda data: data[:-ord(data[-1:])]
    cipher = AES.new(key=key, mode=AES.MODE_CBC, IV=base64.b64decode(data)[:16])
    decoded = cipher.decrypt(base64.b64decode(data)[16:])
    return pkcs7unpad(decoded)
```

With the above functions you can encrypt in PHP - decrypt in python , and vice versa
Assuming that the key has a valid size (16, 24 or 32 bytes)

Comment: Thanks, you have saved my day!:)

Comment: Yes, I have tried it I am receiving error: "binascii.Error: Incorrect padding" my encoded PHP id: "VjceE1sAhxf2kUJYJX5q1BruIco2ne9SBAjzmbgjfno%3D" as I understand something is not right with my encoded ID string I am looking for a solution right now

Comment: I receive same error:/ could it be there is a mistake in decode function?

Comment: Error: 'output = base64.decodestring(input)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/base64.py", line 328, in decodestring
    return binascii.a2b_base64(s)
binascii.Error: Incorrect padding'

Comment: I could make it work with `RIJNDAEL 128` and `openssl_decrypt` ( 128 and 256 ) , but not with `RIJNDAEL 256`

Comment: Very clear and detailed answer, thank you very much!:)